# Two URL's via WebView

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

I have successfully rendered my web app in a Kotlin WebView using the below code.  However I cannot log in.  I am using a separate identity server - which uses a different URL (see the secondurl value in the code).

How do I enable this url to be called from within the webview for login authentication?

```
package com.example.mywebview

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.webkit.ConsoleMessage
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient
import android.webkit.WebSettings
import android.webkit.WebViewClient
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

        private val firsturl = "https://main.mysite.net/"
        private val secondurl = "https://id.mysite.net/"

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

            // Get the web view settings instance
            val setting = webview.settings

            // Enable java script in web view
            setting.javaScriptEnabled = true

            // Maintain webview in app
            webview.webViewClient = WebViewClient()

            webview.loadUrl(firsturl)

        }
}
```

Comment: When do you want to open second url? Are you listening for some post message?

Comment: @mac229 Its at login request - the site redirects to the secondary url, logs in, then returns.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open a webpage login in webview u would use the buttons provided on the webpage and u should enable javascript(since it may contain the function for login).

if that is not what u wish the other option would be:

1. send a post request to server
2. get string or JSON from php on server-side
3. according to the response do what u need to

   ```
    val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text)
   // ...

   // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
   val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
   val url = "http://www.google.com"

   // Request a string response from the provided URL.
   val stringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
       Response.Listener<String> { response ->
           // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
           textView.text = "Response is: ${response.substring(0, 500)}"
       },
       Response.ErrorListener { textView.text = "That didn't work!" })

   // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
   queue.add(stringRequest)
   ```

Source : https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple#kotlin

Comment: Thank you fo the feedback.  My understanding is that the Identity server communicates with the main (Angular) site through the URL string.  Sorry for sounding vague on this - I didn't build the site that I am trying to integrate into a WebView app.

My initial thoughts were that because the second URL isn't declared, it is being blocked by the WebViewClient?

I'm not sure how I would integrate the above into my WebView Client.

Comment: U could try not using chrome client and doing the plain webview like this here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TUXui5ItBkM its just a simple webview with your integration of whateverpage. Just pass the page u want to test faster. And ofc u should always check the reference https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps in case u missed something.

Comment: If you need further help and it's not a secret or if u didn't sign a contract with employer about it message me and i will try to make it work for you.